# Symfony2 + Doctrine-fixtures + DB2: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException] Warning: db2_bind_param(): Describe Param Failed

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I have a problem that I cannot run a fixture set for DB2 as I did for MySQL.

```
>php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
Careful, database will be purged. Do you want to continue y/N ?y
  > purging database
  > loading [3] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadEventTypeData

  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Warning: db2_bind_param(): Describe Param Failed
```

parameters.yml:

```
    parameters:
        database_host: 172.25.x.y
        database_port: 60000
        database_name: dbname
        database_user: user
        database_password: password
        database_driver: ibm_db2
```

Can you give me any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - the problem was a little error on the db-structure. I named a index-item with the same name as the property. No problem for MySQL - but DB2 cannot deal with this. This results to these problems.